# Does long-term exposure to ocean water change the chemical structure of plastic into ocean plastic?

Tags: oceanography, pollution, plastic

I've just been thinking a fair deal about ocean plastic and the ocean clean-up project. Is there something in saline water that changes the chemical composition of most plastics to make them pretty unusable in recycling or is there something else that makes ocean plastic overall a lost cause for recycling?

Comment: You have some mechanical stress and more importantly the plastic is "sitting" in the sun a lot of the time. Also, the challenge is not the recycling, but the collecting.